# Fix blinking effect when scrolling down Recyclerview with custom behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, behavior

I have a code that is experiencing a weird behaviour when scrolling the view down the second time. Basically, the app bar layout should resize the vertical space when swiping down and the user should be able to see the entire image. But when swiping down the second time the screen starts blinking super fast. Any help it'll be greatly appreciated.

ItemDetailFragment.java

```
public class ItemDetailFragment extends BaseFragment implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private static final String TAG = ItemDetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int LOAD_ITEM = 1002;

@BindView(R.id.photo)
ImageView mItemImageView;
@BindView(R.id.rv_item)
RecyclerView rvItem;
@BindView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;

private Unbinder unbinder;
private int currentId;
private Cursor mCursor;
private ItemDetailAdapter mAdapter;
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

public static Fragment newInstance(int id) {
    ItemDetailFragment detailFragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(Commons.ITEM_ID_KEY, id);
    detailFragment.setArguments(args);
    return detailFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    currentId = getArguments().getInt(Commons.ITEM_ID_KEY);

    if(isVisible()){
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rvItem.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new ItemDetailAdapter();
    rvItem.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOAD_ITEM, null, this);
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser){
        setHasOptionsMenu(isVisible());
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_share, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_item_share:
            Log.d(TAG, "Share");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    unbinder.unbind();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return ItemLoader.loadItemById(getContext(), currentId);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (!isAdded()) {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return;
    }

    mCursor = cursor;
    if (mCursor != null && !mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error reading item detail cursor");
        mCursor.close();
        mCursor = null;
    }

    String title = mCursor.getString(ItemLoader.Query.TITLE);
    float price = 0;
    String excerpt = mCursor.getString(ItemLoader.Query.EXCERPT);
    mAdapter.swap(new Item(title, price, excerpt));

    loadItemView();
}

private void loadItemView() {
    if (mCursor != null){
        BindingUtils.loadImage(mItemImageView, mCursor.getString(ItemLoader.Query.PHOTO_URL));
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mCursor = null;
    loadItemView();
}

}
```

fragment_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="la.disfruta.disfruta.custom.behaviour.VerticalScrollingBehaviour"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/barLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_layout_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@color/photo_placeholder"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

VerticalScrollingBehaviour.java

```
public class VerticalScrollingBehaviour extends AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior {

    private static final String TAG = "Behaviour";

    private View mTargetView;
    private View mBanner;
    private View mToolbar;

    private int mInitialHeight;
    private int mExtHeight;
    private int mLastHeight;

    public VerticalScrollingBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VerticalScrollingBehaviour() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, int layoutDirection) {
        boolean layoutHandler = super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
        if(mTargetView == null){
            mTargetView = parent.findViewById(R.id.barLayout);
            mBanner = parent.findViewById(R.id.photo);
            mToolbar = parent.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            if(mTargetView != null){
                init(child);
            }
        }
        return layoutHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View child, View target,
                                  int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        mExtHeight = mBanner.getHeight() + mToolbar.getHeight();

        if (mTargetView != null &&
                (dy < 0 && ( child.getTop() >= mInitialHeight && child.getTop() < mExtHeight) ||
                        (dy > 0 && ( child.getTop() > mInitialHeight && child.getTop() <= mExtHeight)  ) )){
            Log.d(TAG, "onNestedPreScroll - Custom Behaviour");
            resize(dy);
        } else {
            super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNestedPreFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View child, View target,
                                    float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return super.onNestedPreFling(coordinatorLayout, child, target, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View child,
                                       View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == View.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View child, View target) {
        super.onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target);
    }

    private void init(View recyclerView){
        recyclerView.setClipToOutline(false);
        mInitialHeight = recyclerView.getTop();
    }

    private void resize(int dy) {
        mLastHeight = mTargetView.getLayoutParams().height + -dy;
        mTargetView.getLayoutParams().height = mLastHeight;
        mTargetView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

By the way, the activity containing these fragments has a viewpager. I don't know if that would be relevant. But just to let you guys know.

Comment: Is there any solutions for this yet ?